# PrintStream is buffered, but flush does not degrade performance and BufferedOutputStream speeds up performance

Tags: java, performance, buffer

I expected that since PrintStream is buffered, by adding a flush operation after every print(), the speed performance should degrade significantly, but it did not at all, as shown in the below code snippet.

Furthermore, wrapping a PrintStream around a BufferedOutputStream improves performance by more than 10x -- implying that PrintStream is not buffered.

Is PrintStream really not buffered, or does it have a very small buffer, or is there some other explanation for why it does not afford the speed improvement expected from a buffered stream?

```
       // PrintStream is buffered but takes 4228ms to complete
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt") ))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            ps.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(stop - start);

     // PrintStream is buffered, but with auto-flush takes 4140ms to complete, no degraded speed implying flush did nothing
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try (PrintStream os = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt") ))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            os.print(i + " ");
            os.flush();
        }
    }
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(stop - start);
    // PrintStream is buffered explicitly as a BufferedOutputStream and runs quickly: 202ms
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try (PrintStream os = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt")) ))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            os.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(stop - start);
```

Comment: @jtahlborn My question _assumes_ PrintStream _is_ buffered as stated in the source code...my question is why it does not imporve performance like a BufferedOutputStream does.

Comment: guess i misread, i thought you were asking if it was buffered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the internals are "buffered", the write method flushes the internal buffers to the underlying stream on every [write()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.write%28java.lang.String%29).  So in your first two examples, every `write()` is ultimately hitting FileOutputStream.  In your third scenario, you are getting *actual* buffering, where writes are only periodically hitting the FileOutputStream.

If you used your own underlying stream instead of FileOutputStream, you would see that the first two scenarios will result in ~1,000,000 write calls to your stream, whereas the last case will result in much fewer calls (based on the buffer size).

Comment: Very interesting...so in what sense does a PrintStream have a buffer if it always is flushed?

Comment: @Jonathan not really in any sense.  the internal "buffers" are really just there to handle the char to byte conversion.  honestly, PrintStream is really a "legacy" class that you wouldn't really use in practice outside of `System.out`, etc.  Everything it does is done better by some of the newer stream implementations.

Comment: jtahlborn and @Jonathan I was wondering why PrintStream has its own buffer? Do you mean its buffer is the buffer in its `BufferedWriter` field `textOut` http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l69?

Comment: My questions are now in a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318134/how-are-buffer-and-flush-used-in-printstream