# How are buffer and flush used in PrintStream?

Tags: java, io

The question at [PrintStream is buffered, but flush does not degrade performance and BufferedOutputStream speeds up performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680857/printstream-is-buffered-but-flush-does-not-degrade-performance-and-bufferedoutp) wrote that

> PrintStream is buffered, by adding a flush operation after every print(), the speed performance should degrade significantly, but it did not at all, as shown in the below code snippet.
>
> ```
> // PrintStream is buffered but takes 4228ms to complete
> long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
> try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt") ))
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
>         ps.print(i + " ");
>     }
> }
> long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
> System.out.println(stop - start);
>
>  // PrintStream is buffered, but with auto-flush takes 4140ms to complete, no degraded speed implying flush did nothing
> start = System.currentTimeMillis();
> try (PrintStream os = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt") ))
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
>         os.print(i + " ");
>         os.flush();
>     }
> }
> stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
> System.out.println(stop - start);
> ```

The reply at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42682673/10082400 wrote that:

> While the internals of `PrintStream` are "buffered", the write method flushes the internal buffers to the underlying stream on every `write()`.
>
> the internal "buffers" are really just there to handle the char to byte conversion

In the implementation of `PrintStream`, particularly  [`write()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l431), [`print()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l559), and  [`println()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l687),
I see all the write methods call `flush()` only when `autoFlush` is true and the condition it represents is true. Is that contrary to "the write method flushes the internal buffers to the underlying stream on every `write()`" in the answer?

I also see that `PrintStream` indirectly uses [the buffer in its `BufferedWriter` field `textOut`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l69). Where is the internal buffer of `PrintStream` its own?

Comment: Try `try (PrintStream os = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt") )))`

Comment: Yes, I did. But I am asking about the buffer inside PrintStream.

Comment: How big do you think that buffer is?

Comment: `PrintStream` indirectly uses the buffer in its `BufferedWriter` field `textOut`. That is the only buffer I know inside `PrintStream`. Are you asking about its size? I don't know.

Comment: I don't either, but it could be as small as one byte.

Comment: Do you know an unrelated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315444/which-shall-i-convert-a-byte-stream-first-buffer-stream-or-char-stream?